# How to add test case when post a test case result

Tags: rally

The JsonObject addProperty cannot support to add another JsonObject.

The official test shown on below:

```
@Test
public void shouldConstructTheCorrectUrlWithExtraParam() {
    JsonObject body = new JsonObject();
    CreateRequest req = new CreateRequest("Defect", body);
    req.addParam("foo", "Bar");
    Assert.assertEquals(req.toUrl(), "/defect/create.js?foo=Bar&fetch=true");
}
```

What I need is ???:

```
public void shouldConstructTheCorrectUrlWithExtraParam() {
    JsonObject body = new JsonObject();
    body.add("testcase",???)
    CreateRequest req = new CreateRequest("testcaseresult", body);
    req.addParam("foo", "Bar");
    Assert.assertEquals(req.toUrl(), "/defect/create.js?foo=Bar&fetch=true");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a mistake for adding other JsonObject, it's a ref instead a instance.

Works well code:

```
public void createTestCaseResult(JsonObject testCaseJsonObject) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        log.println("createTestCaseResult...");

        String testCaseRef = testCaseJsonObject.get("_ref").getAsString();

        QueryRequest userRequest = new QueryRequest("user");
        userRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("UserName", "Subscription", "DisplayName"));
        userRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("UserName", "=", "lu.han@technicolor.com"));
        QueryResponse userQueryResponse = restApi.query(userRequest);
        JsonArray userQueryResults = userQueryResponse.getResults();
        JsonElement userQueryElement = userQueryResults.get(0);
        JsonObject userQueryObject = userQueryElement.getAsJsonObject();
        String userRef = userQueryObject.get("_ref").getAsString();

        close();
        getRestApi();

        Date now = new Date();
        String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ";
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
        JsonObject newResult = new JsonObject();
        newResult.addProperty("Verdict", "Pass");
        newResult.addProperty("Build", "2014.01.08.1234567");
        newResult.addProperty("Tester", userRef);
        newResult.addProperty("Date", format.format(now));
        newResult.addProperty("CreationDate", format.format(now));
        newResult.addProperty("TestCase", testCaseRef);
        newResult.addProperty("Workspace", workspaceRef);

        CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest("testcaseresult", newResult);
        CreateResponse createResponse = restApi.create(createRequest);

        log.println("createTestCaseResult DONE：");
        log.println(String.format("Created %s", createResponse.getObject().get("_ref").getAsString()));
    }
```